# Having trouble with .NET Generics

Tags: c#, .net, generics

I have the following properties in a class...

```
public IObjectSet<Foo> Foos { get; set; }
public IObjectSet<Baa> Baas { get; set; }
public IObjectSet<PewPew> Pew^2 { get; set; }
```

I wish to return the value of one of those properties, based upon how a pre-determined generic type.

eg.

```
public IObjectSet<T> Set<T>() where T : class
{
    //  THIS CODE DOESN'T COMPILE.
    if (T is User)
    {
        return Users as IObjectSet<T>;

    }
    else if (T is Clan)
    {
        return Clans as IObjectSet<T>;
    }
}
```

So when i have a particular type .. i need to retrieve the correct type data.

eg.

```
return TheClass.Set<Foo>().AsQueryable();
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
if (typeof(T) == typeof(User))
```

Answer (score 2):

`Is` is used when you have an instance, you need to use

```
if (typeof(T) == typeof(User)) ..
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
if(typeof(T) == typeof(User))
```